# GeForce 7200 overheating

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, overheating

I've got NVIDIA GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS

[image: GeForce]

As you can see the video card doesn't have a cooler and doesn't have a connector for it.
It is a passively-cooled video card:

```
Memory Size - 128 MB (TurboCache: 512 MB)
GPU Clock - 450 MHz
Memory clock - 800 MHz
DirectX Hardware Support - DirectX v9.0c
```

But it is overheating. While im not doing anything it reaches to 80°C, while Minecraft is paused - 90°C.

Can I play or use the video card without frying it?

Maybe I should stick 40 mm fan somehow?

**Edit**

Somehow I managed to put 80mm fan on it and connected the fan to motherboard. Now the temperature doesn't raise more then 70°C.

Comment: I think you meant it is a passive video card. The card is very old > 6yrs. The fact that it is still running is impressive. See that your case fan is working. Graphics cards can handle 80-90°C but such temperatures are only reached during load.

Comment: @Serious So I won't be able to fry this card?

Comment: @Serious: "Passively cooled" is a correct description.  Manufacturers also use the term "fanless".  Using the adjective "passive" for electrical devices is ambiguous (e.g. "passive electrical components" has nothing to do with cooling, but rather non-active components such as resistors and capacitors.)

Comment: @Roberts: a fanless video card requires good air circulation around the card and within the computer case.  Simply having a case fan or two is not sufficient for good air flow to cool the video card; you could still have a lot of dead pockets of still air.

Comment: @sawdust Yes, i've got new case and it's closed, only pushing the air out (with casefan)

Comment: @Roberts Is your card overheating recently or since you have purchased it ?

Comment: @Serious I don't know, because didn't purchased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the card is generating artifacts in your display I wouldn't worry.  As Serious mentioned 80-90C is within the normal operating range of a GPU.  Passively cooled cards tend to operate close to the limit since they have a harder time getting rid of the heat.

MacGyvering a fan onto the card, should drop the temps a fair amount but if it's not showing problems there's nothing to worry about.

If you haven't done so, blow any dirt off of the heatsink.  If you feel comfortable you could remove the heatsink and replace the thermal paste, but like adding a fan that's probably overkill.

Comment: How do you mean overkill?

Comment: As in, you'd be doing it out of paranoia rather than to correct an actual problem.